# jQuery mobile button inside collapsible header

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, header

I would really appreciate if somebody could help me. I am trying to dynamically build a collapsible block with jQuery mobile 1.2 Beta (using jQuery 1.7.1).

Now I have the problem that I want to have an button inside a collapsible header and all works fine but when I click on the button the click event I set on it is not fired but instead the block gets uncollapsed or collapsed.

```
$('#main').append('<div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="c" data-content-theme="c" id="pflicht_' 
+ identifier + '" pflichtID="' + val.guid + '">' +
'<h3 style="white-space: normal;" id="inner_header_' + identifier + '">' 
+ header + ': ' + val.pflichtBezeichnung + ' (' + val.Intervall + ' - ' + val.IntModus + ') ' 
+ val.pflichtNummer + '.' + val.pflichtZusatz + 
'<button type="button" data-inline="true" id="ok" pflichtID="' 
+ val.guid + '" identifier="' + identifier + '" >Ok</button></h3>' +
'</div>'

$("#ok").live('click', function () {
                  alert("ok");
              });
```

What do I have to do to get the click event of the button?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Could you format your code a bit, it will become clear and easier to check?:D

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, hope it is better now ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off you should realize that `.live` has been deprecated in favor of [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

That said to understand what's going on here you need to understand how event delegation works in general and `live` in particular, when you use event delegation you bind your event to a higher level in the DOM (some parent element) and then because events bubble up you check the originating event to see if it matches the specified selector.

The `.live` method works by binding the event to the `document` (so it is always bound to a parent element) and then when an event bubbles up to the `document` it checks to see if it matches the selector specified. The issue in your case is that something (probably the *collapisple header*) is swallowing up the `click` event so that it never reaches the document.

The solution is pretty simple, either bind directly to the button, or delegate to a lower level in the DOM, somewhere where your event will reach.

For example

```
$('#inner_header_' + identifier).on('click', '#ok', function(e) {
    alert('ok');
});
```

If you don't want the header to expand and collapse when you click the button, just stop the event from bubbling up further, which you can do using the [stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) method

For example

```
$('#inner_header_' + identifier).on('click', '#ok', function(e) {
    alert('ok');
    e.stopPropagation()
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, your first suggestion works great except that the block gets expanded ... if I use the e.stopPropagation() then I get thrown back to my login screen ... but that maybe has something to do that I am using MVC ASP.NET in combination with jQuery Mobile ... I am not sure

Comment: e.preventDefault(); in combination with e.stopPropagation() did the trick :) ... Thanks again for your help!!

Comment: Glad that worked out for you, I was going to suggest maybe using [stopImmediatePropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/) instead. At any rate you can accept an answer by ticking off the check-mark to the left of the answer.